# Comparar se datas estão no período

Tags: asp

Preciso saber pela data de nascimento do usuário, se ele nasceu no período da ditadura militar.

O período militar no brasil começou no dia 01/04/1964 e terminou em 15/03/1985, etão todos que nasceram entre esse período seriam tratados como true, os antes e depois do período seriam tratados como false.

Estou tentando da seguinte forma, mas estou errando em algo

```
Function ditadura(data)

d = day(data)
m = month(data)
a = year(data)

if a >= 1964 and m >= 04 and d >= 01 or a <= 1985 and m <= 03 and d <= 15 then 
    ditadura = "Você nasceu em um período de ditadura militar"
end if

end function
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode comparar data com data diretamente:

```
Function ditadura(data)

   inicio = CDate("01/04/1964")
   fim= CDate("15/03/1985")
   If data >= inicio And data <= fim Then
      ditadura = "Você nasceu em um período de ditadura militar"
   Else
      ditadura = ""
   End If

end function
```

Só observe o format de data do servidor para definir as datas de início e fim, pode ser que seja necessário usar o format M/D/A

Comment: O código eh bom, mas tem um erro: deveria ser `If data>= inicio And data <= fim Then`

Comment: sim verdade bem apontado @dvd, vou corrigir

Comment: Obrigado amigo, mas não funcionou, verifiquei o format e esta correto, porém quando digito a data 17/10/1983 que estava no periodo, não é informado que eu nasci na ditadura, não ta indo, testei exatamente como vc postou e não foi, aonde posso esta errando? vc fez o teste? foi tudo ok?

Comment: Tem certeza que o forma das datas está correto?

Comment: Acredito que o problema seja o formato d/m/a, tentou com m/d/a?
Fiz um fiddle, um pouco diferente porque é em Vb.Net, mas a lógica é a mesma, e fiz vários testes e funcionou perfeitamente, inclusive com 17/10/1983. Tive de usar o formato de data M/D/A, veja aqui: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1NaBhL

Comment: Funfou mano, depois de testes aqui, verifiquei que a data do nascimento tem que ser no formato d/m/a as outras ficam no formato d/m/a vou tratar aqui e arrumar isso, muito obrigado pela ajuda!